# Error handling for Ajax request in express.js

Tags: node.js, jquery, express

I can't seem to find out how to print a custom error message in alert().

I found this in the express guide

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){

if (req.xhr) {
    res.send(500, {error: 'Oops'});
} else {
    next(err);
}

});
```

I got only to print the error code like this:

```
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
    alert(err);
});
```

But how to i print 'Oops' or any other message that bubbles up to my custom middleware?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse it out of `jqXHR.responseText`:

```
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
  alert(JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText).error);
});
```